# Query com ordenação condicional no MySQL

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho uma tabela chamada `comentarios`, formada pelas colunas: `id`, `descricao`, `criado_em` e `comentario_pai`, como é possível ver na foto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso criar uma query, na qual sejam impressas as respostas depois do seu comentário (`comentario_pai`), exemplo:

1. Comentario 1
2. Resposta 1
3. Resposta 3
4. Comentario 2
5. Resposta 2

Tentei construir algumas querys utilizando o order by, porém não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é o nulo no campo `comentario_pai`.

Uma das formas de resolver é usando o [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
 select * from `comentarios` order by coalesce(comentario_pai, id);
```

Veja o funcionamento no [sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53d4ce/1)

---

`COALESCE` é uma função que que faz parte da especificação [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). Todos os motores de banco de dados que respeitam essa especifição suportam essa função.

O que `COALESCE` faz?

Retorna o primeiro elemento não Nulo da lista passada como argumento da função. Se todos os elementos são Nulos então o resultado é Nulo.

Exemplo:

```
Select coalesce(campo1,campo2,'N.D.')
```

Se `campo1` é não Nulo retorne o `campo1`, se não, avalie o conteúdo do `campo2`.
Se `campo2` é não Nulo retorne o `campo2`, se não, retorne `'N.D.'`.

Aqui está a estrutura interna da funçao `coalesce`:

```
COALESCE(value1, value2, value3, ...)
```

equivale à:

```
CASE WHEN value1 IS NOT NULL THEN value1
     WHEN value2 IS NOT NULL THEN value2
     WHEN value3 IS NOT NULL THEN value3
     ...
     END
```

Comment: Sua solução achei bem simples, porém é interessante que faça uma breve explicação sobre o coalesce, para ajudar outras pessoas que passarem por aqui, eu não conhecia essa função.

Answer (score 2):

Crie um campo que tenha sempre o valor principal. Como no exemplo abaixo e ordene por ele.

```
Select *, 
     CASE WHEN comentario_pai is null THEN id
     ELSE comentario_pai END Ordem
FROM Comentarios
Order By           
     CASE WHEN comentario_pai is null THEN id
     ELSE comentario_pai END
```

Comment: Porque essa resposta foi negativada? Testei aqui no banco e deu certo. Achei sensata essa resposta...